# Building a Dynamic String

Tags: c#

I need to convert an int to a three byte string plus carriage return, and when you check the length of the string it needs to return 4. The string is built dynamically

for example:

```
result = string.Format(@"\x{2}\x{1}\x{0}\x0D", Convert.ToByte(fiveDigitPin.GetValue(0)).ToString("X"),
                           Convert.ToByte(fiveDigitPin.GetValue(1)).ToString("X"), Convert.ToByte(fiveDigitPin.GetValue(2)).ToString("X"));
```

the above returns more than 4 when `result.Length().ToString()` is called

Here is the code (this is .net 3.5)

```
public class iToH
{
    byte[] fiveDigitPin;
    string result;

    public iToH()
    {
    }

     public string extract(string code)
     {
         if (code.Length != 5)
         {
             result = "Please enter a 5 digit pin";

         }
         else
         {
             int pin = int.Parse(code);

             fiveDigitPin = BitConverter.GetBytes(pin);

             result = string.Format(@"\x{2}\x{1}\x{0}\x0D", Convert.ToByte(fiveDigitPin.GetValue(0)).ToString("X"),
                           Convert.ToByte(fiveDigitPin.GetValue(1)).ToString("X"), Convert.ToByte(fiveDigitPin.GetValue(2)).ToString("X"));



         }


         return result.Length.ToString();

     }
}
```

Comment: `"\x01\x25\x54".Length` is 3 for me. You can type this into the C# interactive window for testing. But there is nothing dynamic in your code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem accurately. Don't let us make wild blind guesses about what you really do. Chasing ghosts in the dark is not everyones favourite hobby... ;-)

Comment: Your example simply returns 3 so there must be more to the code causing issues.

Comment: Your code example is still severly lacking. What is `fiveDigitPin` and that mysterious `GetValue` method? How should we try your code if we don't know what that is? How should we know what the produced result string is if we don't know anything about the values/parameters that are used to build this string? What do you mean with "_gives back too many bytes_"? Clearly, you get back a string, not bytes. I can tell that the string contains the hex representation of some (byte???) values, but how exactly are there too many? As already said, ghost chasing is not really a crowd favourite ;-)

Comment: Again, you are still talking in riddles. You say "_returns more than 3_". _More than 3_ of what? What exactly are you talking about? What do you **expect** to get (**precisely!**), but what **exactly** do you get instead? Also, take a close look at your format string there: `"\x{2}\x{1}\x{0}\x0D"`. It will clearly produce a string representing 4 hex bytes (not sure if that is your problem, though...)

Comment: but it doesn't return 4, that is the issue.

Comment: Hold on a minute. This is my last-ditch attempt in understanding your problem. Please pay utmost attention and try to answer my questions here as accurately as possible. Are the bytes in the `fiveDigitPin` array actual character codes? In other words, do the bytes themselves represent actual characters? And do you want those characters represented by those bytes put into a string plus an additional carriage return? For example like: `byte[] { 50, 54, 55 }` -> `result = "267\r"`?

Comment: -elgonzo, thank you for being patient and trying to help me out. Fundamentally this is what I am trying to do.

Comment: -elgonzo, thank you for being patient and trying to help me out. Fundamentally this is what I am trying to do. I want to convert a five digit number to a three byte hexadecimal equivalent plus carriage return (should return 4), for example: 99999 translates to \x01\x86\x9F\x0D but using the code shown above it does not return what I want. When I check the output with "result.lenght" I don't get 4 but 11 for example.

Comment: How does 99999 translate to `\x01\x86\x9F\x0D`? I don't see how you would get `\x01`, `\x86`, `\x9F` when looking at `999`...?

Comment: it does. 99999 is \x01\x86\x9F in hex

Comment: I still don't entirely understand. Lets assume you successfully (theoretically) converted 99999 into the result string, and then you would do `Console.WriteLine(result);` What would you expect to see?

Comment: (Right now it looks to me like you want to convert BCD into binary/integer; but i am totally confused by you using strings...)

Comment: so once converted, and using the `.length` method I need to see the number of bytes the string possess. So  `\x01\x86\x9F` has three bytes in it so that's what it should return not 9 (a byte for each character)

Comment: Why do you want a string with 3 bytes in it? That sounds rather weird and like a XY problem. It's not like you could display or do much other meaningful things with such a string...

Comment: I think you don't really want a string (which is a sequence of unicode characters), but a byte array of length 4. The first 3 bytes should hold the integer input (it is guaranteed to fit in three bytes because the integer is <= 99999), the last should be 0x0D. Is this correct?

Comment: So I do actually need a string. I'm working with someone else's library and the first thing it checks for is the length of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to convert the PIN to a byte array of length 4. The first 3 bytes should hold the integer input (it is guaranteed to fit in three bytes because the integer is <= 99999), the last should be 0x0D.

```
var pin = 99999;
// extract three bytes from pin, append trailing \r
var buffer = new byte[4]
{
    (byte)(pin >> 16),
    (byte)(pin >> 8),
    (byte)pin,
    0x0D
};
```

As you need to pass this as string to a library, you can convert the byte array to an equivalent char array and make a string out of it.

```
var bufferAsCharArray = buffer.Select(b => (char)b).ToArray();
var bufferAsString = new string(bufferAsCharArray );
```

Comment: -Klaus this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!!